# How To Prove This Simple Theorem Using Fitch Natural Deduction System

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Lemma. $ (p \land q) \iff (p \land q \land r) \lor (p\land q\land \lnot r)$

It is clear to me how this is true, but I don’t know how to prove it using only the rules of Fitch-style natural deduction. It is hard without distribution in my armament.

Comment: At least the $\Leftarrow$ direction should be easy.  For the $\Rightarrow$ direction: maybe try double negation, so from $p \land q$ and $\lnot[(p\land q\land r)\lor(p\land q\land \lnot r)]$ you have to derive $\bot$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the $\implies$ direction: derive $r \lor \neg r$. Try to eliminate this disjunction.

Hint for the $\impliedby$ direction: eliminate the disjunction in $(p \land q \land r) \lor (p \land q \land \neg r)$

Edit: full solution for $\implies$ direction

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\[0ex]\hline #2\end{array}}$

$$
\fitch{p \land q}{
\fitch{\lnot(r \lor \neg r)}{\fitch{r}{r \lor \neg r\\\bot}\\\neg r\\r \lor \neg r\\\bot}\\ \neg \neg (r \lor \neg r) \\ r \lor \neg r \\ \fitch{r}{p \land q \land r \\ (p \land q \land r) \lor (p \land q \land \neg r)}\\ \fitch{\neg r}{p \land q \land \neg r \\ (p \land q \land r) \lor (p \land q \land \neg r)} \\ (p \land q \land r) \lor (p \land q \land \neg r)}$$

Comment: 1. assume $(p \land q)$.              1.1. $(p \land q) \lor (r \lor \lnot r)$ by $\lor$.I                                                    However, I need $(p \land q) \land(r \lor \lnot r)$ Note the subtlety. I don’t know if there is a $\land$ intro rule where you can introduce something always true. I’m stuck here.

Comment: Assume $\neg (r \lor \neg r)$. What can you say if you have $r$? What can you say if you have $\neg r$? Do you see a way to derive a contradiction, so that $\neg \neg (r \lor \neg r)$ (and thus $r \lor \neg r$)? You can derive $r \lor \neg r$, without doing anything with $p \land q$ at all.

Comment: 1. Assume $\lnot(r \lor \lnot r)$. 1.1. Assume  $r$. Then, $r \lor \lnot r $ 1.2. Assume $\lnot r$. Then, $\lnot r \lor r$. 1. Therefore, $r \lor \lnot r$. Therefore, $\bot$. Therefore $\lnot \lnot (r \lor \lnot r)$ Is there a double negation rule to claim that is the same as $r \lor \lnot r$?

Comment: In 1.2 you don't assume $\neg r$, but rather derive it from 1.1. Yes, it's called double negation elimination

Comment: Can you please provide a full answer for the hard direction?

Comment: I added an answer, without the corresponding rules (not sure how to do this in mathjax). You should be able to figure out which rules were used though.

Comment: Rather than proving LEM and then using it, we may as well fold everything into one indirect proof.$\small\begin{align}\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~~p\land q}{\fitch{~~2.~~\lnot((p\land q\land r)\lor(p\land q\land\lnot r))}{\fitch{~~3.~~r}{~~4.~~p\land q\land r\\~~5.~~(p\land q\land r)\lor(p\land q\land\lnot r)\\~~6.~~\bot}\\~~7.~~\lnot r\\~~8.~~p\land q\land\lnot  r\\~~9.~~(p\land q\land r)\lor(p\land q\land\lnot r)\\10.~~\bot}\\11.~~\lnot\lnot((p\land q\land r)\lor(p\land q\land\lnot r))\\12.~~(p\land q\land r)\lor(p\land q\land\lnot r)}\end{align}$